# How to remove a specific color from a whole pdf document?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, pdftk

Is their a way, with imagemagick, pdftk or other stuff, to remove a specific color from a whole pdf document?

I mean, I give an html hex color code to a tool, and it remove all occurences of this color from a pdf file.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use imagemagick to convert one color to another, including an rgba value; if the page background is predicable, white say, you can replace the color in question with that. Suppose you want to replace red `#ff0000` with (transparent) white, then you can use something like this:

```
convert input.pdf -fuzz 10% -fill 'rgba(255,255,255,0)' -opaque '#ff0000' output.pdf
```

(The fuzz value sets how closely to the color in question it needs to match.)

Comment: I got the following error message `convert-im6.q16: attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF' @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/421.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `output.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3229.`. It seems I should allow imagemagick to perform this kind of operation.

Comment: Well, I solve the previous problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion) solution but the command you give didn’t delete the targeted color and in addition, it transform the pdf into a bitmap witch is not desirable.

Comment: Imagemagick pretty much only works on rasterized images, so that is definitely a downside. Converting to svg with inkscape and just changing colors with sed then converting back might be a possibility, but it would be a lot easier to test with the actual file rather than speculate blindly.

Comment: I planed to do the convertion into svg with inkscape and come back to pdf. But the inkscape convertion break the fonts (and so other vectorial effects) :/ That’s why I whant to avoid inkscape solution, also manualy.